# How to format number in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to convert some numbers to chars according to the following logic :

```
Input     => Expected Output  |   Current Output 
0         => 0                |   0.00  << Wrong
.1111     => 0.11             |   0.11
.1        => 0.1              |   0.10  << Wrong
1.111     => 1.11             |   1.11
```

Basically my logic is to have the minimum of characters. Only the user friendly caracters that describe the number.

Here is my current function

```
to_char(Value,'9999999999999990D99');
```

As you can see for 0 for example, it returns 0.00

Does anyone know how to solve that please ?

Thanks.

Comment: The output is not "wrong"  It is formatted against the mask you provided.  You probably can't accomplish this without creating your own pl/sql function that has some checks for the specific conditions you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want this one:

```
rtrim(to_char(Value,'fm99999999999990D99'),'.')
```

Ie, you need to add 'fm' in format mask and them remove '.':
Example:

```
select 
  to_char(Value,'9999999999999990D99') xx 
 ,to_char(Value,'fm9999999999999990D99') x_fm  -- just FM
 ,rtrim(to_char(Value,'fm99999999999990D99'),'.') x_fm_trim -- FM + rtrim
from xmltable('0, 0.1111, 0.1, 1.111' columns value number path '.');

XX                   X_FM                 X_FM_TRIM
-------------------- -------------------- ------------------
                0.00 0.                   0
                0.11 0.11                 0.11
                0.10 0.1                  0.1
                1.11 1.11                 1.11
```